# Serializer removing data in Django 3.1

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to validate data in order to store it. But the serializer is removing valid fields. Here my code:

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model): 
    user_id = models.UUIDField('action uid',default=uuid.uuid4,null=False,primary_key=True,blank=False,editable=False, unique=True)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    latitude = models.CharField('Latitude', max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    longitude = models.CharField('Longitude', max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField('datatime', null=False, blank=False, editable=False)
```

serializer.py

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

view.py

```
def save_my_data(self, request):
  user_info ={
    "user_id": resquest.user.user_uid,
    "city": resquest.user.city,
    "latitude": "17.6801",
    "longitude": "83.2016",
    "datetime": timezone.now()
  }
  serializer = serializers.MyModelSerializer(data=user_info)        
  serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) # Not error thrown.
  print( serializer.data ) # returns void
```

Any thoughts about this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you get `data` from at the line where you access `data['user_uid']`?
Please show your view how it's really written in your code, the current example should throw since there is no `data` defined

Comment: @GProst I have updated the function

Comment: Are you really sure that this code is executed at all?

Comment: Yes sir, I have even put a `print(user_info)` before `serializer = serializers.MyModelSerializer(data=user_info)`  it shows the data, after that call as well and after the `.is_valid` and it does the prints

Comment: are you sure the ***`resquest.user.user_uid`*** is retunring the ***"correct and valid data"*** ?

Comment: Yes I't sir, I have inspected it, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64212851/serializer-removing-data-in-django-3-1/#comment113549090_64212851) please as well @Arakkal Abu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't call the ***`.save()`*** method of the serializer

```
serializer = serializers.MyModelSerializer(data=user_info)        
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

print("This is validated data, ", serializer.validated_data)
serializer.save()
print("This is saved data, ", serializer.data)
```

### Update

Some of the model fields are set as **`editable=False`** which causing the issue. DRF thinks that those fields shouldn't be edited, which in turns the fields into ***`read_only`***.

So,

#### Method 1

Remove **`editable=False`** and migrate

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(
        'action uid',
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        null=False,
        primary_key=True,
        blank=False,
        editable=False,
        unique=True
    )
    # other fields
```

#### Method 2

Explicitly define *corresponding fields* in the serializer class.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.UUIDField()
    # other `editable=False` fields

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: When I do `serializer.save()` it throws an error because the `user_id` can't be null

Comment: doesn't that make sense? You are not passing the data, that's why the error

Comment: BTW, you can inspect the ***`serializer.validated_data`*** to know which all data points are validated ***just before the DB write/save operation***

Comment: That's the problem, this line: `serializer = serializers.MyModelSerializer(data=user_info)` is removing valid data.

Comment: are you sure the ***`resquest.user.user_uid`*** is retunring the ***"correct and valid data"*** @Jefferson

Comment: Yes I't sir, I have inspected it, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64212851/serializer-removing-data-in-django-3-1/#comment113549090_64212851) please as well @Arakkal Abu

Comment: @Jefferson Updated the answer